# Python unicode issue when iterating over list

Tags: python, django

I have an Excel workbook which I want to scroll through the contents of the first column and write each unique value to a new workbook i.e. no duplicates.

This code, without checking for duplicates, works fine:

```
def get_data_from_sheet(sheet_index, start_row, end_row, count):
for row in range(start_row, end_row):
    cell = sheet.cell(row,0)
    count = count+1 
    if row != start_row:
        sheet1.write(count,0,cell.value)
return count
```

However when I try to add a condition to check for duplicates, nothing is written to the Excel file:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

def get_data_from_sheet(sheet_index, start_row, end_row, count):
for row in range(start_row, end_row):
    cell = sheet.cell(row,0)
    count = count+1 
    if row != start_row:
        list.append(smart_str(cell.value))
        if smart_str(cell.value) not in list:
            sheet1.write(count,0,cell.value)
return count
```

Which puzzles me, because the list contains the values i.e.:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling this:

```
    list.append(smart_str(cell.value))
```

before this:

```
    if smart_str(cell.value) not in list:
```

You are sure that the test will be always `False`, as you append the value to the list just before testing it is not in it. You have an issue with the logic here.

NB: avoid calling your variables with built-in types, call your list object `lst` or anything else making sense but don't use `list` as a variable.

Comment: @user578582: also, incrementing `count` should be inside the `if` suite, otherwise you will get an empty row where each duplicate was in the original file.